# Android: My CheckBox "checkAll" don't update the checkbox item of my ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, unchecked

**My situation:** an activity with a button, a checkbox checkAll and a custom ListView with image,name,surname and checkbox

**Problem:** when i click on checkAll, the listView doesn't update the vale of each checkbox in the listView(whic have to be all checked).

Here there is my MainActivity with the listView:

```
private final static int INFO_DIALOG = 1;
private ListView mList;
private CheckBox checkAll;
private Button buttonCreaPartita;
private Person[] people;
private int peopleSize;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout_select_friend);      

     mList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);  //the listView 

     NewQAAdapterSelectFriends adapter= new NewQAAdapterSelectFriends(this); 
     //my adapter
     MainActivity.this.people = new Person[]{ //add person to my array of Person
            new Person(1,"Belen", "Rodriguez", R.drawable.belen,false),
            new Person(2,"Cameron", "Diaz", R.drawable.cameron,false),
            new Person(3,"Jessica", "Alba", R.drawable.alba,false),
            new Person(4,"Yolanthe", "Cabau", R.drawable.cabau,false), 
            new Person(5,"Belen", "Rodriguez", R.drawable.belen,false),
            new Person(6,"Cameron", "Diaz", R.drawable.cameron,false)
            };

     peopleSize=people.length;
     adapter.setData(people); //pass the array of person to my adapter
     mList.setAdapter(adapter);   //set the adpater   

    checkAll =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAll);//my CheckAll  checkbox
    checkAll.setChecked(false);//default value

    checkAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if((checkAll.isChecked())){

                for(int i=0;i<peopleSize;i++){
                    people[i].setCheck(true); 
                                   //update the new value on the array
                   ((BaseAdapter) mList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged() ; //i'll try to refresh the value of checkbox in the listview
                 }
            }

            else if(!(checkAll.isChecked())){
                for(int i=0;i<peopleSize;i++){                                                people[i].setCheck(false);
                                                ((BaseAdapter) mList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged() ;
                        }       
            }
        }
    });        
}


  buttonNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    //after user select the person on the list press buttonNext to go to next Activity
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Person[] selectedFriends=new Person[peopleSize];
            int countSelected=0;
            for(int i=0;i<peopleSize;i++){
                if(people[i].isCheck()){            
                    selectedFriends[countSelected]=people[i];
                    countSelected++;
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Numero elemento:"+countSelected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intentMenu=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Partita Creata", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(intentMenu);
        }
    });
```

This is my adapter with the getView function():

```
    public class NewQAAdapterSelectFriends extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Person[] data;
boolean[] checkBoxState;
ViewHolder viewHolder;

public NewQAAdapterSelectFriends(Context context) { 
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public void setData(Person[] data) {
    this.data = data;
    checkBoxState=new boolean[data.length];
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        checkBoxState[i]=data[i].isCheck();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int item) {
    return data[item];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_select_friends, null);
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.nameText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personName);
        viewHolder.surnameText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personSurname);
        viewHolder.contactImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personImage);
        viewHolder.checkBox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.nameText.setText(data[position].getName());
    viewHolder.surnameText.setText(data[position].getSurname());
    viewHolder.contactImage.setImageResource(data[position].getPhotoRes());
    viewHolder.contactImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                   checkBoxState[position]=true;
                   data[position].setCheck(true);
               }else{
                   checkBoxState[position]=false;
                   data[position].setCheck(false);
               }
            }
        });
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
    return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameText;
    TextView surnameText;
    ImageView contactImage;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    CheckBox checkAll;
}
}
```

**With log i'm sure that when i click on checkAll all my items change their value in true (checked), but this is not show on the relative checkbox that stay all unchecked...**

Thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CeckAll button in a list with a lot of elements in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319581/ceckall-button-in-a-list-with-a-lot-of-elements-in-android)

Comment: Did you try setting the listener OnCheckedChangeListener() ?

Comment: I don't think it'll make it work if it isn't but I would move notifyDataSetChanged() out of your for loop.  That way you just update the adapter once, might improve performance.

Comment: @feelingtheblanks Yes i tried yet OnCheckedChangeListener..same result

Comment: @MinceMan I tried without any result.

Comment: @Tim No Tim, in the other post i had the problem of nullPointerExcpetion on the invisible items of ListView when i click on checkAll. I solved this problem, and in this post i have a different problem...when i click on checkAll the items are checked correctly but no result is show on display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you to pass `Person []` through your `Adapter`'s constructor like this:

```
public NewQAAdapterSelectFriends(Context context, Person[] p) { 
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = p; //set class level variable.
}
```

wipe out all `boolean[] checkBoxState;` from adapter, since you have state reference in person class i.e `people.setCheck(true);`. so instead of using `checkBoxState` use `data[position].getCheck()` like this:

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(data[position].getCheck()); //to set check box state.
```

Remove `setData(Person[] data)` method too, and hope it all will go well.

Comment: Thanks Adil :D...your suggestion fixed my problem perfectly.